# NLog file logging from visual studio but not when running from executable

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nlog

I recently updated the namespaces in my c# visual studio project and since then, everything is running OK except the NLog (from NuGet Packages) is no longer logging to the usual files (in a folder within My Documents).

I have updated the NLog.config file so that the name attribute of the rules / logger element includes the new namespace.

Has anybody else had the same problem? Let me know if more information is required - but because it is working OK when running from within Visual Studio, I wasn't sure exactly which information would be needed.

Best regards
Ann

Comment: When using namespace in Nlog, it read them case sensitive, so make sure all is written correctly. Source: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes I have checked this. 
I have also tried adding my NLog config file text to the application config file, but I get the same results. Works from development environment but not from application executable file (whether run from the project directory or the program files install directory).

Comment: Have you tried to Run that executable as `Administrator`? Maybe there is a permissions issue? Also in the `.conf` file, did you specify the absolute path staring from `C:\`

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I have tried to run executables as admin and it still doesn't write. 
There are no absolute paths in my config file (now embedded in my application config file). I use paths such as: 
'<target name="SAMSLog" xsi:type "File" fileName="${specialfolder:folder=MyDocuments}/SAMS Logger/SAMSLog-${LogDay}.csv'

Comment: Try enabling [NLog Internal Logging](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging) to see why NLog isn't working correctly. You can also take a look at [NLog Logging Troubleshooting](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting).